# two column layout with right column having 3 rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am learning css grids but i find grid-template-areas, columns and row very difficult to understand. I tried to design chat screen layout where there will be two columns. Left column will have list of conversations and right column will have three rows. One as chat title which will be fixed and another row will be for list of messages and third row will be a form to send message which will also be fixed. I tried to do in the following way but its not working as expected

```css
.chat-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "chat-list chat-title chat-title" "chat-list message-list message-list" "chat-list chat-form chat-form";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-title {
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.chat-list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.message-list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.chat-form {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <section class="chat-list">
    Chat List
  </section>
  <section class="chat-title">Chat title</section>
  <section class="message-list">
    Message List
  </section>
  <section class="chat-form">Chat form</section>
</div>
```

I have mentioned chat-list three times for every row but still I don't see chat-list block with chat-form. How can i layout 2 column with right column having 3 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the areas to the classes:

```css
.chat-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "chat-list chat-title chat-title" "chat-list message-list message-list" "chat-list chat-form chat-form";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-title {
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  grid-area: chat-title;   /*  added */
}

.chat-list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  grid-area: chat-list;   /*  added */
}

.message-list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  grid-area: message-list;   /*  added */
}

.chat-form {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: chat-form;   /*  added */
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <section class="chat-list">
    Chat List
  </section>
  <section class="chat-title">Chat title</section>
  <section class="message-list">
    Message List
  </section>
  <section class="chat-form">Chat form</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My bad, I missed grid-areas part. Seems like using position:fixed on chat-title and form makes the layout broken. Anyway, I will look into it. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, indeed, position: fixed will not work well inside a grid. It is somehow against the main idea of grid.